# What are the best practices for Testing in Angular?

Tags: angular, testing, angular-test

I have an `AppComponent` and in its html template, I have `BannerComponent` and `WelcomeComponent` (indicated by `<app-banner>` and `<app-welcome>`).
So in the test case, if I declare the real components, I'll also have to declare their nested components and provide for all services injected in any component in the tree.
What is the recommended practice? Can I just use `imports: [ AppModule ]` or do I declare all the components and their nested components and all the services injected into them??

If I just import AppModule, will it take the real `RouterModule` (if used by the `AppModule`) or can I just override it by using `RouterTestingModule`??

If I declare all the component, will give me a better idea that the component under test integrates well with all the other dependent components. Is it a good practice? Also, is it a good practice to use `APP_ERRORS_SCHEMA`?

Answer (score 0):

We create a TestModule that declares all the dependencies for testing components, in there we declare MockComponents for all the selectors that component will use in their templates. Most of these mock components just have text in their templates but some do a bit more if we need them to render DOM objects.

Sometimes we just declare other components in the spec file if they are simple and have no dependencies.